# Anyone has selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies jar file with fixes advs to adv for new android version

Tags: selendroid

Error screenshot:

Getting an error when run selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar file 
[image: Getting Error when run selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar file]

I tried so hard to create jar file from master https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/tree/master/selendroid-standalone 
jar file but getting sync failed error. can anyone create or have new fixes jar file of selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar (fixes advs to adv command)

> Java file :selendroid-standalone\src\main\java\io\selendroid\standalone\android\implDefaultAndroidEmulator.java needs to replace advs to adv command

I am getting errors when i tried to open this project in android studio and due to that i can't rebuild it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the it's clearer on what you're asking? Example: telling us what is exactly the error you have, what have you tried to do to fix it, etc...

Comment: i just edit question and add screenshot